# Spark XML Tags are missing when null values are coming

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, databricks

Below is the dataframe I have.

```
+-------+----+----------+
|   city|year|saleAmount|
+-------+----+----------+
|Toronto|2017|      50.0|
|Toronto|null|      50.0|
|Sanjose|2017|     200.0|
|Sanjose|null|     200.0|
|  Plano|2015|      50.0|
|  Plano|2016|      50.0|
|  Plano|null|     100.0|
|Newyork|2016|     150.0|
|Newyork|null|     150.0|
| Dallas|2016|     100.0|
| Dallas|2017|     120.0|
| Dallas|null|     220.0|
|   null|null|     720.0|
+-------+----+----------+
```

I tried to convert that to xml using

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
    .option("rowTag", "ROW")
    .save("myxml")
```

but some of the tags are missing in the xml like below

```
<ROWS>
    <ROW>
        <city>Toronto</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Toronto</city>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Sanjose</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>200.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Sanjose</city>
        <saleAmount>200.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year>2015</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <saleAmount>100.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Newyork</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>150.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Newyork</city>
        <saleAmount>150.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>100.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>120.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <saleAmount>220.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <saleAmount>720.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
</ROWS>
```

***DataFrame when it printed, as shown above its giving all null values correctly. But when converted to XML the corresponding xml element tags are missing... Is this the way databrics XML api works ?***

In above xml `year` is missing...  since `year` value is `null` in the dataframe.

Is there any option in [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) s in which `null` value tags are also displayed ?

Comment: any one...  pls help me to find out how tags are missing when they are null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output null tags, you need to provide a default `nullValue` that will appear in the tag:

```
df.write.format("xml")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .option("nullValue", "")
    .option("rowTag", "ROW")
    .save("myxml")
```

will yield

```
<ROWS>
    <ROW>
        <city>Toronto</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Toronto</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Sanjose</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>200.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Sanjose</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>200.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year>2015</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    ...
</ROWS>
```

Now this may be a very bad idea because you can't specify a different value per tag and thus it's very easy to generate xml files that can't conform to any XSD they should.

In the above example, to read the generated file, you need to set the `treatEmptyValuesAsNulls` option to true or specify a `nullValue` option :

```
val df = spark.read.format("xml").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true").load("myxml")

or 

val df = spark.read.format("xml").option("nullValue","").load("myxml")
```

Comment: i used this option treatEmptyValuesAsNull true but not working for me as afore mentioned. other option i.e. option("nullValue","") was working for me

Comment: pls remove treatEmptyValuesAsNull from your answer which is not working.

Comment: `treatEmptyValuesAsNulls` is useful only when reading xml data not saving (I had a typo in the option name that I fixed).  You can find some usage of these options in the spark-xml test suite: https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/databricks/spark/xml/XmlSuite.scala

Answer (score 0):

`.option("nullValue","")` is working for me not `option("treatEmptyValuesAsNull","true")` which you have already used and didnt get desired output

used below dependencies/versions

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-xml_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.1</version>
            </dependency>

           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

Complete example :

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, sum}

object SparkXmlTest extends App with Logging {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName(this.getClass.getName)
    .config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val sales = Seq(
    ("Dallas", 2016, 100d),
    ("Dallas", 2017, 120d),
    ("Sanjose", 2017, 200d),
    ("Plano", 2015, 50d),
    ("Plano", 2016, 50d),
    ("Newyork", 2016, 150d),
    ("Toronto", 2017, 50d)

  ).toDF("city", "year", "saleAmount")
  sales.printSchema()

  val first = sales
    .rollup("city", "year")
    .agg(sum("saleAmount") as "saleAmount").sort($"city".desc_nulls_last, $"year".asc_nulls_last)


  logInfo("group by city and year")
  // The above query is semantically equivalent to the following
  val second = sales
    .groupBy("city", "year") // <-- subtotals (city, year)
    .agg(sum("saleAmount") as "saleAmount")
  second.show


  logInfo("group by city ")
  val third = sales
    .groupBy("city") // <-- subtotals (city)
    .agg(sum("saleAmount") as "saleAmount")
    .select($"city", lit(null) as "year", $"saleAmount") // <-- year is null

  third.show

  logInfo("group by for grand total")

  logInfo("final df using union of group by city and year / group by city /group by to get grand total")
  val fourth = sales
    .groupBy() // <-- grand total
    .agg(sum("saleAmount") as "saleAmount")
    .select(lit(null) as "city", lit(null) as "year", $"saleAmount") // <-- city and year are null

  fourth.show

  fourth.printSchema()
  first.union(second).union(third).union(fourth)
    .coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .mode("overwrite")
    //.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
    .option("nullValue", "")
    .option("rowTag", "ROW")
    .save("sparkxmltest.xml");
}
```

Resultant XML with desired output :

```
<ROWS>
    <ROW>
        <city>Toronto</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Toronto</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Sanjose</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>200.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Sanjose</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>200.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year>2015</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>100.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Newyork</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>150.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Newyork</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>150.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>100.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>120.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>220.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city></city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>720.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Toronto</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Sanjose</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>200.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <year>2017</year>
        <saleAmount>120.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year>2015</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Newyork</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>150.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>100.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year>2016</year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>220.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Plano</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>100.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Newyork</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>150.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Toronto</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>50.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city>Sanjose</city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>200.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <city></city>
        <year></year>
        <saleAmount>720.0</saleAmount>
    </ROW>
</ROWS>
```